# Is there a way to get from Douala to Brazzaville/Kinshasa with terrestrial public transport?

Tags: overland, gabon, brazzaville

How can I travel overland from Douala to Brazzaville/Kinshasa by terrestrial public transport? (Meaning I don't have a vehicle and don't want to drive or hitchhike.) Bus, train, and the like.

I care about a fair balance of cheap and fast. I don't want to spend two weeks doing this, nor do I want to spend more money than I must.

I found [this story](http://www.wanderingsavage.com/2011/07/so-you-want-to-go-from-cameroon-to-namibia-on-public-transport-heres-more-than-youd-ever-want-to-know/) about travelling from Douala to Namibia.

I'm considering going from Douala to Kinshasa myself. So I'd like to see an overview of costs. I guess visa costs (for EU/Dutch citizen) will be biggest chunk of this.

There's a boat from Brazzaville to Kinshasa so the dangers in DR Congo are not really an issue.

See also these two related questions:

- [Is it safe to travel through Congo-Brazzaville?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38559/is-it-safe-to-travel-through-congo-brazzaville)
- [Is it safe to travel in Gabon?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/is-it-safe-to-travel-in-gabon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer you're going to get is from someone who's done it which, as you linked in your question, would be [this guy](http://www.wanderingsavage.com/2011/07/so-you-want-to-go-from-cameroon-to-namibia-on-public-transport-heres-more-than-youd-ever-want-to-know/).  If you follow his instructions to get from Douala to Pointe-Noire it's then a simple case of getting the [Congo-Ocean Railway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congo%E2%80%93Ocean_Railway) straight to Brazzaville.  The only part he gives only the option of hitching is Bifoum to Lambaréné:

> you want to get off at the Lambaréné-Libreville junction in Bifoum,
>   just 70 kilometers from Lambaréné, and hitch a ride from there. Pay
>   2-3,000 CFA for the ride from Bifoum to Lambaréné.

Going off his rough costs, it's about 20 euro (12,000 CFA) for each leg.

Visa prices are prone to change, but [70 euros for Gabon](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Gabon), [US$141 for Cameroon](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cameroon) and [GBP60+ for the Congo](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/republic-congo/passport-visa).