# Is it safe to travel through Congo-Brazzaville?

Tags: safety, brazzaville

Is it safe to travel overland through Congo Brazzaville? (Not DR Congo.) Which dangers can I expect except from malaria?

Spin-off from [Is there a way to get from Douala to Brazzaville/Kinshasa with terrestrial public transport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38521/whats-a-good-way-t-oget-from-douala-to-brazzaville-kinshasa-with-terrestrial-pu)

I'd also like to know if there are any dangers along the road aside from malaria. Are there places, towns, border crossings to avoid because of insurgencies or other types of violence?

Comment: How would you define "safe"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The travel advisory from [France](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays/congo-12306/) or [Belgium](http://diplomatie.belgium.be/fr/Services/voyager_a_letranger/conseils_par_destination/afrique/congo_brazzaville/ra_congo_brazzaville.jsp) sound rather positive. Usually I would not answer based only on that but since they tend to be conservative in their advice, it seems Congo is not a country of particular concern.

The only thing mentioned are the usual (for African countries) warnings about poor neighborhoods, road travel and going out at night. Some attacks on travelers have apparently been reported in the border regions (the border with the Central African Republic in the North, in the Cuvette Ouest *département* near Gabon and in the Pool *département* outside of Brazzaville itself in the south) but some of these reports might be old.